# How can I resolve a 403 Forbidden error after deploying a Symfony 5 app in production on Hostinger?

Tags: deployment, symfony5

Im working in Symfony 5 Project. All its OK in dev, but after deploy app in production, i have "403
Forbidden. Access to this resource on the server is denied".
I host project to Hostinger. All my projects is in public_html root folder, and .htaccess - index.php are in public folder
Please help and thanks
My .htaccess content:

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # This Option needs to be enabled for RewriteRule, otherwise it will show an error like
    # 'Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden'
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I have tried to

- change permissions folder in production with: "chmod -R 777 public/"
- cache:clear in prod

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've taken various steps to try and fix the 403 Forbidden error. However, one crucial aspect to look at, especially with Symfony applications, is your DocumentRoot configuration in your hosting setup.

In a typical Symfony application, the DocumentRoot should not point to the root directory of the project but rather to the public directory within the root. This public directory is where the front controller (index.php) and your assets (like CSS, JavaScript, images) live.

Please ensure that your hosting configuration points the DocumentRoot to the public directory of your Symfony project, not the root directory of the project. The path would look something like this /path_to_your_project/public.

This adjustment is often necessary when moving a Symfony application from development to production. Let me know if this resolves your issue!